# msi with embeddedchainer fails on uninstall with "bad handle"

Tags: windows-installer

I finally got my embedded chainer msi running, with four sub msi's being installed via Installer.InstallProduct in my C# chainer.exe (like described in the one and only chainer example found elsewhere here on stackoverflow).
My problem: if I uninstall the package afterwards, when "transaction.Join" is called, this time it failes with MSI error: bad handle. I have to kill the msiexec.exe process in taskmanager, and then everything is running ok.

Any suggestions?

Addendum: I'm using Windows Installer 4.5, and there is only one entry in the MsiEmbeddedChainer table. The four msi's are handled one after another by the chainer executable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally, the problem is fixed: there is a bug in the standard example for a c# embedded chainer:

In the line:
IntPtr ptr = new IntPtr(Convert.ToInt32(args[0], 16));
the "16" must be changed to "10"!

Otherwise, if there are more than 10 transactions started by the embedded chainer (as in my setup, where five sub msi's are installed), the handle that is used by "transaction.Join" will be wrong at some point and gives the "bad handle" error.

Many thanks to Microsoft for their help with this problem!

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of suggestions to check:

1) Transaction processing of multiple-package Windows Installer installations is not supported by Windows Installer 4.0 and earlier versions.  Windows Installer 4.5 or later is required to roll back the installation of multiple packages as a single transaction. The Windows Installer functions that might cause problems when the installer installs, repairs, updates, or removes applications is listed here: [Multiple-Package Installations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/En-US/Library/Windows/Desktop/c4a0f4d8-818d-4e60-908b-adaa2a54de95).

2) If there are multiple entries in the [MsiEmbeddedChainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/En-US/Library/Windows/Desktop/ac1e9c7b-bb83-4e1e-9108-211374c7d878) table. Only one embedded chainer can be launched. If multiple entries have both been conditioned to run, it is undefined which entry will run.

Comment: As added above, I use Windows Installer 4.5, and there is only one entry in the MsiEmbeddedChainer table. Any help would be appreciated...